# paging gridview rebinding for each result

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

i have a gridview with paging featuer,when i want to search item in DB and result displayed in gridview with paging
but when i jump another page gridview will Bind and list all items in DB with all pages,how can i solve this problem?
thanks in your advise

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }
}

private void BindGridView()
{
    using (NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1 dbContext = new NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1())
    {
        var query = from list in dbContext.Students
                    select list;
        lblStudentsCount.Text = query.Count().ToString();
        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridView();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're calling GridView1.DataBind() at the end of your BindGridView() method, so I don't believe you need to do it again after your call for BindGridView(); in the PageIndexChanging event:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridView();
}
```

If this didn't solve it, please let me know what happens in the comments and I'll take another look at it.

Also, if you're saying that your GridView is filling up with all items from the database (when you're expecting only certain items), that indicates a problem with your query.  I would try setting a breakpoint and step through the query to see what is coming back, just to make sure you're getting back your expected results.